# Is This a Raspberry Pi 3 B or B+?

Tags: pi-3

I have an odd question to ask. I'm only new to Raspberry Pi's and recently acquired my first one. However I'm struggling to find the difference(s) between the Raspberry Pi 3 I bought, and the B+ model as shown in a previous answer. From the layout of the board I've got, it looks like (for all intents and purposes) the B+ model. However, on closer inspection on the motherboard, it says 'Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2' .

[image: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B??]

Can someone tell me what the difference is? Do I have the B+ version? If not, can someone explain to me what the difference is between the models? Is it something that I should be worried or concerned about?

Comment: New answer below shows the chip layout of a 3 B+ for comparison.

Answer (score 8):

**That couldn't have been a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+... because that model didn't exist!**

Until March 2018, the only Pi to have a Model B+ version is the [original Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/processor-microcontroller-development-kits/8111284/). The differences between the **Pi 1** Model B and B+ are as follows:

> - Tidier layout
> - 40 General Purpose Input/Output Pins (GPIO) compared to 26 on the Pi B
> - Improved connectivity (4 USB Ports compared to 1)
> - Improved audio quality
> - Lower power consumption. Switching power regulators reduce the power consumption to between 0.5 W and 1 W
> - Push-push microSD card slot

Regardless, since your Pi specifically says 'Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2', you can be absolutely sure it is, as stated, a Pi 3 Model B.

In fact, the Model B was the only model of Pi 3 available as of late 2017—[the Pi 3 Model A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50256/what-happened-to-raspberry-pi-2-and-3-model-a) hadn't yet been released.

You might also like [this identification guide](https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2016/11/21/how-to-identify-which-model-of-the-raspberry-pi-you-have) if you're in any doubt as to what type of Pi you have.

Comment: One of the comments in this link have a python scripts that translate the model ID to a comprehensible name: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72239/how-does-raspbian-know-its-been-installed-in-a-pi-or-compute-module/72242?noredirect=1#comment113679_72242

Comment: Thanks to those who answered. I've now been able to determine the type of board I have. It's an a02082 revision board made by Sony.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Your first statement is now wrong :D

Comment: @Giorgio Good spot, thanks, that's now fixed... although it does destroy the dramatic effect a little ;)

Answer (score 4):

[The Raspberry Pi 3 B+ does exist now <sub>(release date 2018-03-14)</sub>](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/)

However at the time of the question the 3 B+ didn't exist *yet*. On the picture you can see that on the PCB it says *Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2*

[image: B not B+ !!1]

---

Comment: Can I can check with a command code if I have a Raspberry `3B+`?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of "B series" pi models goes.

- Raspberry pi model B, BCM2835, two USB2 host ports, 10/100 Ethernet, 256MB or 512MB of ram. Released Febuary 2012
- Raspberry pi model B+ BCM2835, four USB2 host ports, 10/100 Ethernet, 512MB of ram. Released July 2014
- Raspberry pi 2 model B BCM2836, four USB2 host ports, 10/100 Ethernet, 1GB of ram. Released February 2015
- Raspberry pi 3 model B BCM2837, four USB2 host ports, 10/100 Ethernet, 1GB of ram, 2.4GHz wifi, bluetooth. Released February 2016
- Raspberry pi 3 model B+ BCM2837B0, four USB2 host ports, 10/100/1000 Ethernet (though limited to about 300M in practice by the USB bus), 1GB of ram, dual band wifi, bluetooth. Released March 2018
- Raspberry pi 4 model B BCM2711B0, a total of five USB ports (two USB3 host, two USB2 host, one USB2 OTG), 10/100/1000 Ethernet (no longer bottlenecked by USB bus), 1GB/2GB/4GB ram. Released July 2019

The key thing is that just because they dropped the + from the name when they released the next generation does not mean that they dropped the improvements made. A "Raspberry pi 2 model B" or "raspberry pi 3 model B" is better than a "Rasperry pi model B+". A "Raspberry pi 4 model B" is better than a "Raspberry pi 3 model B+".

Your Pi is a Raspberry pi 3 model B which was the latest at the time you wrote your post.

Answer (score 0):

**The inscription you quote is from a regular model 3B**

**Also, the chip layout is clearly not a B+**

[image]

This is the layout of a 3 B+

---

The 1024 MB (1 GB) variant is now available.  The price is $44.95

[Element14 Raspberry Pi 3 B+](https://smile.amazon.com/Element14-Pi-Modell-Raspberry-Motherboard/dp/B07BDR5PDW) (Amazon)

Comment: It should say 1024MB variant, not GB.