# Can a Raspberry Pi 4 be used as USB gadget but draw power from elsewhere?

Tags: usb, power-supply, pi-4

Assuming that the Raspberry Pi 4 is attached as a slave to emulate different devices/gadgets using the USB OTG functionality available on the USB-C port: Is it possible to power the Raspberry from another power source at the same time?

Put differently: Is it possible to attach one USB/non-USB device (like a power bank or battery) which powers the Raspberry while another USB device is acting as the USB host (like a smartphone or PC)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to power the Raspberry Pi from another power source at the same time. You can use a POE (Power Over Ethernet) hat or power it by the +5V and GND GPIO pins. The latter has the disadvantage that it isn't protected against overload. Or you can try to do it yourself an **Y**-cable [How to make a splitter cable for the USB2 OTG port on the RPi 4B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100667/79866).

Comment: I'd say YOU HAVE TO power it,I tried directly on my computer, the pi does'nt even boot up