# Is it possible to log in Raspberry Pi 4B using USB cable?

Tags: usb, pi-4, login

The idea comes from this website [4 ways to connect RPi4 to the Internet](https://dev.webonomic.nl/4-ways-to-connect-your-raspberry-pi-4-to-the-internet).
The author said that it is possible to SSH into RPi4 using that method. But my
PC only provides 5V 500mA current through USB Type A standard. I use external
5V 3A power supply for RPi4. So, if I cut out the DATA connections from the USB
cable and connect it to PC, can I open a shell to log in RPi4?

As an illustration, see the USB Type A connector pinouts from [Wikipedia:USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USB.svg).

I want to remain the Pin1(+) and Pin4(-) from the power supply. Then cutout the
Pin3(D+) and Pin2(D-) and connect it to PC using a USB extension cable. My main
goal is to open a shell and log into the OS in RPi4.

Comment: sure, give it a go, let us know how it went

Comment: I did not know this setup is called USB OTG. I follow [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103466/113332).