# how to configure usb in raspberry pi as otg

Tags: otg

How can I configure usb port available in raspberry pi to OTG ?

Comment: If you skim through this you will find some links: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100583/where-is-the-usb2-otg-port-on-the-rpi-4-model-b-located

Comment: the TLDR of it is ... it's the USB C power  port that can be OTG on the pi 4

Comment: did you read goldilocks link? do that

Comment: @KA No, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB2 OTG port is inside the USB-C connector so you may have to do some "special" hardware setup to use OTG Gadget mode, if you mean that. You can find more information at [Where is the USB2 OTG port on the RPi 4 Model B located?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100583/79866).  I may also be of interest [How to make a splitter cable for the USB2 OTG port on the RPi 4B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100667/79866).